# set imageView height to be 3/4th of its parent

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I set height of imageView within layout xml file to be 3/4th of its parent layout height, full width and  videoView to occupy the rest ?

Following is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.blynq.player.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `weight` to achieve so.

Set the parent to be a `LinearLayout` and add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4"
```

to the parent and

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="3"
```

to the child you wish to make 3/4. To the other child, add

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="app.com.blynq.player.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <VideoView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout and set weight.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.blynq.player.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:weight="3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```